# Join a table representing a "transfer" between two rows of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

Sorry for the confusing title; however a description and illustration should hopefully clear it up.

Essentially, I have the table `A` representing instances of a transfer of an 'amount' between rows of table `B.` I wish to join `A` with `B` so that I can display the details of the transfer:

```
================= A ===================
+-----+-----------+----------+--------+
| AID | fromID(FK) | toID(FK) | amount |
+-----+-----------+----------+--------+
|  1 |          1 |        5 |    100 |
|  2 |          1 |        3 |    150 |
|  3 |          5 |        3 |    500 |
|  4 |          1 |        5 |    200 |
|  5 |          4 |        5 |    800 |
|  6 |          3 |        5 |     15 |
+----+------------+----------+--------+
```

and

```
==== B =====
+----+------+
| BID | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | a    |
|  2 | b    |
|  3 | c    |
|  4 | d    |
|  5 | e    |
+----+------+
```

I wish to join them and produce a "from name" column and a "to name" like:

```
+-----+------+----+--------+
| AID | from | to | amount |
+-----+------+----+--------+
|   1 | a    | e  |    100 |
|   2 | a    | c  |    150 |
|   3 | e    | c  |    500 |
|   4 | a    | e  |    200 |
|   5 | d    | e  |    800 |
|   6 | c    | e  |     15 |
+-----+------+----+--------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can join `a` on `b` twice:

```
SELECT aid, from_b.name, to_b.name, amount
FROM   a
JOIN   b from_b ON from_b.bid = a.fromid
JOIN   b to_b ON to_b.bid = a.toid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with out `join`.

[Fiddle with sample data](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c15af/1)

```
select aid, 
(select name from b where a.fromid = bid) as "from",
(select name from b where a.toid = bid) as "to",
amount
from a
```

Comment: Correlated subqueries are generally slower than joins. This is poor technique.

Comment: @HLGEM Actually, because of the optimizer, from SQL 2005 on, this query would almost always be the same.  (there are more complex cases where it might not be)

Answer (score 1):

Do a `JOIN` between the tables like below but you will have to join table `B` twice

```
select a.AID, 
b.name as [from],
b1.name as [to],
a.amount
from A a
join B b on a.fromID(FK) = b.BID
join B b1 on a.toID(FK) = B.bid;
```